# Android variable check not working

Tags: android, variables

I want to change the setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds attribute of a button. It should display a different icon, depending on the counter_notification variable. For example the log shows me this, but nothing changes. What am I doing wrong?

```
11-04 14:40:57.728  20765-20765/ADebugTag﹕ Test1: 2
11-04 14:40:57.728  20765-20765/ADebugTag﹕ Test2: true
11-04 14:40:57.728  20765-20765/ADebugTag﹕ Test3: false
11-04 14:40:57.728  20765-20765/ADebugTag﹕ Test4: false



        public void doNotification() {
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                final Button notification_text = (Button) findViewById(R.id.notification_text);
                notification_text.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                Log.d("ADebugTag", "Test1: " + counter_notification);
                Log.d("ADebugTag", "Test2: " + variable1);
                Log.d("ADebugTag", "Test3: " + variable2);
                Log.d("ADebugTag", "Test4: " + variable3);

                if(counter_notification==1){
                if(variable1=true){
                    benachrichtigung_text.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds( R.drawable.icon_1, 0, 0, 0);
                } if(variable2=true){
                    benachrichtigung_text.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds( R.drawable.icon_2, 0, 0, 0);
                } if (variable3=true){
                    benachrichtigung_text.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds( R.drawable.icon_3, 0, 0, 0);
                }
                } if(counter_notification==2){
                if(variable1=true){
                    benachrichtigung_text.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds( R.drawable.icon_1_1, 0, 0, 0);
                } if(variable2=true){
                    benachrichtigung_text.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds( R.drawable.icon_2_1, 0, 0, 0);
                } if (variable3=true){
                    benachrichtigung_text.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds( R.drawable.icon_3_1, 0, 0, 0);
                }
                } if(counter_notification==3){
                if(variable1=true){
                    benachrichtigung_text.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds( R.drawable.icon_1_2, 0, 0, 0);
                } if(variable2=true){
                    benachrichtigung_text.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds( R.drawable.icon_2_2, 0, 0, 0);
                } if (variable3=true){
                    benachrichtigung_text.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds( R.drawable.icon_3_2, 0, 0, 0);
                }
                }
            }catch (Exception e) {

            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Indent your code properly, please

Comment: if(variable3=true) should be if(variable3==true) or if(variable3)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your check are made with assignement instead of comparison

```
if(variable1 == true)
```

instead of

```
if(variable1 = true)
```

you should take the habit to write it the other way so you can't make the mistake you did :

```
if(true == variable1)//can't forget one of the '=' because it won't compile
```